# SQL Server Syntax failure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am running the following code and I am getting a syntax error near '.TableReference' error, the code use to work then I did something and now I have this error and I can't seem to find the issue

Through troubleshooting I have narrowed the code issue to the `' FROM ' + @TableName` section but it appears to be good code.

```
BEGIN
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TableName AS NVARCHAR(MAX) --The Fully qualified database name
    DECLARE @Ref AS NVARCHAR(MAX) --The name of the Table we are processing
    DECLARE @TempTab AS NVARCHAR(MAX) --the temporary table we are subjecting to the tortures of this process
    DECLARE @TempQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX) --Query to move all data into the temporary table

    --This selects the first record in the Website Request Table which hasn't been processed and passes it into the TempTab variable
    SET @NDTRef = (SELECT TOP 1 Reference from dbo.WebRequestTable Where Processing IS NULL)
    SET @TableName = 'Processing.dbo.'+@NDTRef
    Set @TempTab = 'TEMP' + @NDTRef 
    SET @TempQuery = 'SELECT * INTO '+ @TempTab +' FROM ' + @TableName 
    EXEC sp_sqlexec @TempQuery;

    END
```

Any help would be appreciated it is a stand alone instance of SQL Server 2019 and the code is a part of a stored procedure but the rest of the code runs off the temporary table created in this block

After suggestions I put in a print statement regarding the @TempQuery when put straight after and the EXEC removed the output is

```
SELECT * INTO TEMP2294690 FROM Processing.dbo.2294690
```

With the EXEC back in play I get the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17 Incorrect syntax near '.2294690'.

The print output after the EXEC shows:

```
SELECT * INTO TEMP2294690 FROM Processing.dbo.2294690
```

The Table 2294690 exists in the database Processing the Temp2294690 is a table that should be created by this block but it isn't being created

Comment: What is the content of `@TempQuery` right before execution

Comment: You debug dynamic SQL by using `print(@TempQuery)` instead of exec. Then you have static SQL and its trivial to debug.

Comment: If you are still unsure, post the output from `print`.

Comment: I don't think you can start a database name with a number (it may depend on the compatibility level of your database). Try escaping it `[Processing].[dbo].[2294690]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, [regular Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers) must begin with a letter, an underscore (`_`), at sign (`@`) or the number sigh (`#`).
(There are other rules as well, but this is the one relevant to the question...)

Identifiers that don't follow the rules of regular identifiers can be only used if they are enclosed in square brackets (`[]`) or double quotation marks (`"`).

The best way to handle identifiers when creating dynamic SQL statements is to use the built in [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function - this way you can make sure your query doesn't break even if the identifier doesn't follow the rules of regular identifiers.

So your SQL should look like this:

```
SET @TableName = '[Processing].[dbo].'+ QUOTENAME(@NDTRef)
SET @TempTab = 'TEMP' + @NDTRef 
SET @TempQuery = 'SELECT * INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@TempTab) +' FROM ' + @TableName
```

That being said, you should also probably check my blog post entitled [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server/) where you can find some more information about how to safely create dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much I wasn't aware of the tables not being pure numbers, once the names were changed it worked

Answer (score 0):

You know that if the view is temporary only you can see it and if you close your session user the view is deleted and dont save try with create view dont temp and drop after you read.

If all previus you have it in your mind you could try this for see if the view has created --> its a extract of Microsoft official pagge:

VIEW_METADATA

Specifying the instance of SQL Server will return the DB-Library, ODBC, and OLE DB APIs the metadata information about the view instead of the base tables when you request the browse mode metadata for a query that references the view. Browse mode metadata is additional metadata that the SQL Server instance returns to these client-side APIs. This metadata enables client-side APIs to implement updateable client-side cursors. Browse mode metadata includes information about the base table to which the columns in the result set belong.